# Sinatra API Authentication and Ember.js

Tags: ruby, mongodb, authentication, ember.js, sinatra

I am still on the "design" part of my app and have decided to use Ember.js as front-end, Sinatra and MongoDB as back-end and my question is as follows:

I want to use Sinatra and MongoDB merely to give Ember.js persistence, so how would I go about authentication and authorization? Should I use an specific gem or should I write auth from scratch?

The app will have the classic CRUD operations.

I also considered if whether or not do I need Sinatra at all or I can just connect Ember.js directly to MongoDB and whether or not that would be a good idea (if even possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do need Sinatra.  You may be able to connect directly to Mongo but it would probably be like pulling teeth to get it all to work correctly.  It'll probably be easier to massage data server side with Sinatra.

For auth you could checkout ember-auth : http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs